# Execute function using Npgsql 7

Tags: c#, dapper, npgsql

I'm running PostgreSQL 15 and added both Dapper and Npgsql 7.0 to my project. I need to run the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_posts(
    start_date date default null,
    end_date date default null,
    user_id integer default null,
    take_rows integer default 10,
    skip_rows integer default 0)
 RETURNS SETOF post_info
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT .....
END;
$function$
;
```

Then I tried the following piece of C# code to execute this query and return the resultset:

```
using (var reader = await connection.ExecuteReaderAsync("get_all_posts", 
                   new
                   {
                       start_date = postRequest.StartDate as object ?? DBNull.Value,
                       end_date = postRequest.EndDate as object ?? DBNull.Value,
                       user_id = postRequest.UserId as object ?? DBNull.Value,
                       take_rows = take,
                       skip_rows = skip,
                   }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
// ...
}
```

This causes the error saying that get_all_posts is not a procedure (Npgsql 7.0 stopped accepting the `CommandType.StoredProcedure` for functions).

And then tried to use the SELECT statement like this:

```
using (var reader = await connection.ExecuteReaderAsync("SELECT * FROM get_all_posts($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)", 
                   new
                   {
                       start_date = postRequest.StartDate as object ?? DBNull.Value,
                       end_date = postRequest.EndDate as object ?? DBNull.Value,
                       user_id = postRequest.UserId as object ?? DBNull.Value,
                       take_rows = take,
                       skip_rows = skip,
                   }, commandType: CommandType.Text))
{
// ...
}
```

But in this case the error was `bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires`.

How's the correct way of getting Npgsql and Dapper to execute PostgreSQL function?

Answer (score 1):

CommandType.StoredProcedure has been changed to invoke stored procedures in Npgsql 7.0, see the [release notes](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/7.0.html#a-namecommandtypestoredprocedure-commandtypestoredprocedure-now-invokes-procedures-instead-of-functions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know it has changed, in fact, that information is already in my question. The problem is that Npgsql in their example uses `NpgCommand` and parameters (internally using the index to assign the $1, $2, etc.) but I'm using `Dapper` and it is using anonymous object to add parameters

Comment: Dapper indeed doesn't use positional parameters ($1, $2). So simply replace those with Dapper's named placeholders, e.g. `@StartDate`, `@EndDate` (make sure to adjust the names in the anonymous object to correspond).